# Ignore NULLs in ORDER BY CLAUSE

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

**EDIT**: I have changed the characters to integers to better represent my issue - not sure if it makes a difference to the actual `ORDER BY` Clause. The Original dataset can be found at the bottom of this question.

Is it possible to **ignore** `NULLS` in the `ORDER BY CLAUSE`?

I have a query which I run which currently gives me this:

```
COL1     COL2     COL3
-----------------------
111      111      100
112      NULL     200
113      115      100
NULL     112      400
NULL     114      250
```

But I want it to ORDER BY to look like this:

```
COL1     COL2    COL3
-----------------------
111      111      100
NULL     112      400
112      NULL     200
NULL     114      250
113      115      100
```

I want the ORDER BY to ignore the `NULLS` in `COL1`.
BUT I still want it Ordered by each column.

`ORDER BY COL1, COL2, COL3`

---

**ORIGINAL DATASET**

```
COL1     COL2     COL3
-----------------------
111      AAA      100
112      NULL     200
113      EEE      100
NULL     BBB      400
NULL     DDD      250
```

Comment: Based on the data sample you provided, `ORDER BY COL2` seems to be what you're looking for.

Comment: It doesnt work because i need it to order by COL1 first then COL2

Comment: Show some more representative data.

Comment: Sorry I have updated the question to better represent my issue

Comment: Now Col3 looks like the best one to use

Comment: @SpectralGhost heheh.

Comment: Hahah okay I think it now represents the scenario i want to show :)

Comment: Hahah okay I think it now represents the scenario i want to show :)

Comment: There is no way to know that 112 should be the 3rd row in Col1 without ordering somewhere else first because there are NULLS in rows 2 & 4.  You'd then need to order by Col2 OR Col3 first but you're saying you need to order by Col1 first...So short answer: No.

Comment: I think `ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY COL1 ORDER BY COL1 ASC) ASC, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY COL2 ORDER BY COL2 ASC) ASC, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY COL3 ORDER BY COL3 ASC) ASC` can get you close, but still for the ordering of `NULL     BBB      400` before `112      NULL     200` and `NULL     DDD      250` before `113      EEE      100` will need some additional logic for the sorting (as indicated by @koppinjo; not sure what that would be though)

Comment: If you can explain why the 112,NULL,200 should come after the NULL,BBB      ,400 rows, then I might be able to help.

Comment: @SpectralGhost Because the order by will simultaneously order both columns and ignore the Nulls in either column. would it make a difference if COL2 was a number too?

Comment: @cocojay I need a logical explanation on why exactly one is done before the other. Simultaneous ordering on two columns is magic and doesn't exist. You need to think about it and write exact rules. If you can do that, then you can order it how you want.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server cannot return the result set as you wish. It has no information telling it that the NULL value for COL1 on the record that also contains 'BBB' and 400 comes between 111 and 112. Sorts have an order of precedence and will only use the secondary and tertiary sort clauses when there is a match in the preceding clause value.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** After reviewing, I'm not sure that the result set that OP desires is possible without a severely specific (and potentially nested) `CASE` statement in the `ORDER BY`, as the desired output is not actually ordered in a predictable way as far as SQL is concerned.

---

Since there is no reliable way to get SQL to do this without hard-coding your order by with every possible null condition, I don't recommend doing this for any kind of production query or procedure, but for a one-off query, you can get the data you want by abusing the `ISNULL` or [`COALESCE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) functions in SQL Server:

```
ORDER BY ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar, COL1), ISNULL(COL2, (CONVERT(varchar, COL3))))
```

Basically, you're creating an order hierarchy by saying, "Order by COL1. If it is null, use COL2. If that is null, use COL3"

Here's what it looks like in action:

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE (COL1 int, COL2 varchar(10), COL3 int)

INSERT INTO @temp VALUES(111, 'AAA', 100)
INSERT INTO @temp VALUES(112, NULL, 200)
INSERT INTO @temp VALUES(113 , 'EEE', 100)
INSERT INTO @temp VALUES(NULL, 'BBB', 400)
INSERT INTO @temp VALUES(NULL,'DDD', 250)

SELECT * 
FROM @temp
ORDER BY ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar, COL1), ISNULL(COL2, (CONVERT(varchar, COL3))))
```

And here are the results:

```
  COL1  COL2  COL3
-------------------
  111   AAA   100
  112   NULL  200
  113   EEE   100
  NULL  BBB   400
  NULL  DDD   250
```

You can also use a `CASE` statement in the `ORDER BY`, if it's easier for you to read:

```
SELECT * 
FROM @temp
ORDER BY 
CASE
    WHEN COL1 IS NOT NULL 
        THEN CONVERT(varchar, COL1)
    WHEN COL2 IS NOT NULL 
        THEN COL2
    ELSE 
        CONVERT(varchar, COL3)
END
```

Again, though, I would like to reiterate, there is no real way for SQL to give you results like this without hard-coding your conditions like this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - it looks almost there except `COL2` is not ordered in the results you have but COL1 looks good. Is it possible using your method to get COL2 to order too?

Comment: You're right, I didn't notice that. Now that I look closer, I think Rob Epstein may be right. Unless you made a massive `CASE` with utra-specific conditions, I don't think it's possible. Even if you replaced `NULLS` with some arbitrary value, the result set is not really ordered.

Answer (score 0):

Here is example:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (COL1 INT, COL2 VARCHAR(100), COL3 INT)


INSERT INTO @table SELECT 111, 'AAA', 100
INSERT INTO @table SELECT NULL, 'BBB', 150
INSERT INTO @table SELECT 112, 'CCC', 200
INSERT INTO @table SELECT NULL, 'DDD', 250
INSERT INTO @table SELECT 113, 'EEE', 300




SELECT * 
FROM @table
ORDER BY CASE WHEN COL1 IS NULL THEN 999 ELSE COL1 END, COL2, COL3
/*result
COL1    COL2    COL3
111     AAA     100
112     CCC     200
113     EEE     300
NULL    BBB     150
NULL    DDD     250
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

**The closest I can get to is this**

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE (COL1 INT,
                 COL2 VARCHAR(10),
                 COL3 INT)

INSERT INTO @temp
VALUES(111, 'AAA', 100)
INSERT INTO @temp
VALUES(112, NULL, 200)
INSERT INTO @temp
VALUES(113 , 'EEE', 100)
INSERT INTO @temp
VALUES(NULL, 'BBB', 400)
INSERT INTO @temp
VALUES(NULL, 'DDD', 250)

SELECT COL1,
      COL2,
      COL1
FROM @temp
ORDER BY ISNULL(CAST(COL1 AS VARCHAR(10)), '') + ISNULL(COL2, '') + ISNULL(CAST(COL3 AS VARCHAR(10)), '')
```

**RESULT:**

```
COL1    COL2    COL3
111     AAA     100
112     NULL    200
113     EEE     100
NULL    BBB     400
NULL    DDD     250
```